# How to reuse a map view once it's rendered

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been searching this for a while but couldn't find a solution.

My app has several views (pretty common ones like table or map) and i provide a menu to allow users switch between them, which is implemented with segue. i noticed that every time i switch to a map view(and other views as well) the map view will be rendered from scratch. I might not understand the term "render" perfectly. by render i mean the background starts with grey grid and then map starts showing up in pieces.

Is there a way i can say something like: only render this map view once and all subsequent switches to this view will reuse what was rendered in the first time?

thanks in advance for any answers!

```
// here is how I store a reference of target view controller
self.tableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

// this function does the switch
func swapFromViewController(from:UIViewController, to:UIViewController) {
    from.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.addChildViewController(to)
    currentController = to

    self.transitionFromViewController(from, toViewController: to, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: {
        (finished:Bool) -> Void in
        self.transitionInProgress = false
    })
}

// function call looks like:
self.swapFromViewController(currentController!, to: tableViewController)
```

Comment: If you post some code of how you change your views, I might be able to show you some examples of to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the views by making a new instance of the ViewController, they will always "begin" from scratch. If you unwind back to the view, this problem should be fixed.

I'm not very sure how the MapKit View works. If unwinding doesn't help, you can use a container view and add the view of your MapKit into this container. To change views you'll have to add the view of the new ViewController on top of your current view and keep the view of your MapKit so you can use it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your view is being unloaded from memory when you switch away from the view, then loaded again once the user segues back into the view. The only way to keep this from happening is to keep a reference to the view controller with the map in it somewhere, then present that view controller. This could be as simple as storing it in a `UIViewController` property on a singleton object. You can then dismiss and present this controller wherever you want - since it's stored in memory it will use the same instance of the controller and, in turn, the same map view.

Be careful here, though, you don't want to store view controllers that take up massive amounts of memory in your program. If you really have to then do it, but be aware of iOS application memory restrictions.